# React .Net core project setup for Azure.. VS react template or Separate projects

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core

I need to develop an React + .Net core application that will deployed to Azure instance. My issue is I've read that some articles says I will need 2 Azure services to host the app.
1 : For React frontend
2 : .Net core Web API application

Do I need to have 2 Azure service instanced to deploy. One for React JS and one for .Net core APIs?

I'm planning to do the development in the Visual studio .Net React template app. In it, the React app and .Net core Web API's are in the same project. If I use this template, will I be able to deploy the React app and .Net core API project separately?

Or Should I keep the React JS , JavaScript project (npx create-react-app my-app) separately and .Net core Web API project separately?

What will be the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. For example, if you're planning to use the APIs for your mobile app as well, it is better to go for two different services, one app or service for your react static web app and one app service / API management for your APIs. So that you can scale up your API app if there is a demand. And services like Azure CDN helps you to cache and serve the static app, which gives better performance.